# How to get the volume level in the software that plays the audio (not the system volume) in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, media-player, volume, naudio

I monitor the input volume in the computer (i.e the volume in the computer's mixer, not the system volume/the output volume) in C# using the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library:

```
inputVolume = device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue;
```

Now, the input volume also depends on the software/media player that plays the audio - either Windows Media Player, the WMP browser plugin or any other software (like VLC, Winamp, Quciktime, etc).

My problem is that I need to know when the user changes the input volume through the software that plays the audio. When a user increases the volume level in the software, for example, it increases the input volume - but I can't know if it's because the stream itself is "louder" or because the user has increased the volume level in the software that plays the audio.

If the user just increases the computer system volume, it doesn't affect anything, because it's the output volume and I don't care about it.

The audio is not from a file on the user computer but rather from a live stream through the internet (it can still be played on audio applications that are installed on the computer and not only in the browser).

Is it possible to get the volume level in the software that plays the audio? It's usually the Windows Media Player browser plugin, but it can also be a different software.
If it's not possible, is there any workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp

Comment: @m4ngl3r I only need the volume level in the volume bar which is inside the player that plays the audio in the computer. Does this mean I have to play the audio through C#? Would that even help? I don't think so..

Comment: Does the software playing the audio offer an API? Your best bet if to stream the audio through your own software.

Comment: @user2140261 It's almost always WMP browser plugin, but I wasn't sure if I can use any Windows Media Player API with C# since it's playing in the browser.

Comment: It means, use the Volume property on WaveChannel32 instead. Also, unless you are using an old version of NAudio, the BlockAlignReductionStream and the WaveFormatConversion stream are unneccessary, since MP3FileReader emits PCM.

Comment: @m4ngl3r Thanks for the response, can you give me some more guidance on how to use it? Can you write it as an answer? I'm not experienced with NAudio at all..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = new WaveOut();
var file = new AudioFileReader(@"test.mp3");
var meter = new MeteringSampleProvider(file);
meter.StreamVolume += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", e.MaxSampleValues[0],e.MaxSampleValues[1]);
player.Init(new SampleToWaveProvider(meter));

var form = new Form();
form.Load += (s,e) => player.Play();
form.FormClosed += (s,e) => player.Dispose();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Some useful links

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966422/can-i-measure-external-applications-sound-levels-from-c)

[So Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142569/detect-current-volume-level-while-a-file-is-playing-using-naudio)

Comment: I should have mentioned, the audio is not from a file that is on the computer - it's from a live stream through the internet. Is that a problem?

Comment: Then you should get the streams, wait i just found some article like that. ll give you the link.

Comment: This isn't helpful in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992798/how-to-programmatically-get-the-current-audio-level

Comment: It's irrelevant, I already have the audio stream level in the mixer, but I need the audio level in the *software that plays the audio*, not in the computer mixer.